# Disable reverse image search on website?

Tags: javascript, image, search

I have a site with user profile pictures.  I would like to protect the identities of the users, but Chrome (and other browsers) default to allowing reverse image searches on the jpeg images.  Is there a way to post pictures while preventing reverse image search on them? What actually causes this option to appear on the right click menu on some images and not on others?

Comment: If you're serving up the images over HTTP, then there's nothing you can do to prevent people using them any way they want to. You could add an authentication layer to ensure that only registered users have access, and then use legal means to enforce policies.

Comment: What is preventing me from downloading the image and running the reverse image search? If you don't want to share something don't give people access to it.

Comment: If you have public access to a resource, then there's nothing you can do about it beyond ensuring that only appropriate users have access to the content, as suggested above.

Comment: There is no way to prevent a reverse image search, if the images are visible, they can be used in a RIS.

Comment: @leigero has a good answer, For what it is worth, if you use a div with a background set rather than an img tag I think you can also avoid the context menu option (at least in chrome)

Answer (score 0):

You may consider disabling the right-click menu on the image to prevent them from accessing any options "copy, search etc.". This is primarily a deterrent.

```
<img oncontextmenu="return false" src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
```

Any savvy user, though, will be able to do whatever they want with the image. Once it has been loaded in a browser the user owns the image locally.

Comment: Yeah, it's merely a deterrent. The user can simply disable JavaScript and get round this. Or they can just take a screen capture of the window and copy it. So, most devs do not even bother employing such measures these days.

Comment: Not to mention is *really* annoying for legitimate users too.

Answer (score 0):

If you publicly publish an image on the internet, it can be downloaded and reverse searched. Be it with chrome right click or a more manual way.

There is no way you can prevent that. At most you will be able to make it a few seconds longer to reverse search the image.

Comment: This should be a comment

Comment: @dippas well, I'm not asking for more information or suggesting improvements. I'm just answering : « You can't ».

Answer (score 0):

> I have a site with user profile pictures. I would like to protect the identities of the users, but Chrome (and other browsers) default to allowing reverse image searches on the jpeg images.

That's novel, but once an picture is delivered to any client, they can do whatever they want with it.  They have the file.  They could access the image from their file system and simply do a manual reverse search.

> Is there a way to post pictures while preventing reverse image search on them?

No, there is essentially no way to prevent this from happening.  If someone can see the picture, they have it.  There are ways to deter them, but any person slightly inclined to get the picture will find a way, be it disabling JavaScript, accessing browser cache, or simply taking a screenshot.

> What actually causes this option to appear on the right click menu on some images and not on others?

That option shows up because the browser has the option for it.  Since the browser is a client-side tool, you can't directly control it.  No matter what you try to tell the client-side, the client can simply ignore your directions.

---

The safest way to protect your users is to not expose these images to the public net.  Secure them behind some kind of authentication scheme on a private network and make sure to serve them over https.